# Bash Image Processing

Tags: bash, files, move

All,

OK! Trying to move image file to central images folder.  Here is my script:

```
img_dir='/home/filies/images/'
img_fil='/home/files/img_dump.txt'
i='0'
while read -r fline
do
   fpath=$(dirname "$fline")"/"
   fname=$(basename "$fline")".$i"         
   nfile="$img_dir$fname"
   if [ ! -e "$nfile" ]; then
#      mv "$fline $img_dir$nfile"
      echo "NF=> $nfile"
   else
      ((i++))
#      mv "$fline $img_dir$nfile.$i"
      echo "F=> $fname P=> $fpath"
   fi 
done < ${img_fil}
exit
```

File moves currently commented out, till I get this right or have at least a likable result.

There are dups and my current script will not increment the counter for just the dupes of the same filename but for every dupe occurrence.

Is there a better way to do this and/or can I create a subroutine that does a search in the new image dir to find the latest increment number?

Cheers

OMR

Comment: filies?  Really?

Answer (score 1):

You could do with a loop in your script:

```
nfile="$img_dir$fname"
while [ -e "$nfile" ]
do
  ((i++))
  fname=$(basename "$fline")".$i" 
  nfile="$img_dir$fname"
done
```

Now you have an unused filename

Answer (score 0):

You can load them into an array with globbing and use the array size:

```
shopt -s nullglob
dups=("$nfile".*)
shopt -u nullglob
i=${#dups[@]}
((i++))
```

The numbering goes from 1 up, so when the file count is 0, you still need to increase it once to get 1. Setting `nullglob` is needed as otherwise the array size would be 1, as explained here: [How to create a possibly empty array from filename glob?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426816/how-to-create-a-possibly-empty-array-from-filename-glob#426817). `shopt -u nullglob` does the reverse, ie. it unsets the `nullglob`.

There's a gotcha here with other filenames fitting the pattern `"$nfile".*`. `*` will match anything, not just numbers, so be warned.

The whole would look like this:

```
img_dir='/home/filies/images/'
img_fil='/home/files/img_dump.txt'
#i='0'
while read -r fline
do
   fpath=$(dirname "$fline")"/"
   fname=$(basename "$fline")".$i"         
   nfile="$img_dir$fname"
   if [ ! -e "$nfile" ]; then
      mv "$fline $img_dir$nfile"
      echo "NF=> $nfile"
   else
      shopt -s nullglob
      dups=("$nfile".*)
      shopt -u nullglob
      i="${#dups[@]}"
      ((i++))
      mv "$fline $img_dir$nfile.$i"
      echo "F=> $fname.$i P=> $fpath"
   fi 
done < "${img_fil}"
exit
```

Notice the line

```
i='0'
```

is commented out. Firstly, because in this situation it is not needed. Secondly, if you use another way of solving this, beware that the value of `i` would stay increased after each `while` loop if you don't reset it.

I added `.$i` for you in this line, so remove it if that's not what you want:

```
echo "F=> $fname.$i P=> $fpath"
```